# SIMPro - Application URI

Tags: json, json.net

I'm trying to extract data from SIMPro.  According to the API documentation I need to set up authorization.  The documentation states

> To authenticate via OAuth, consumer credentials must be established.   Consumer credentials can be managed by an authorised user, go to System > Setup, and then select API > Applications (on the left hand side). Finally, select 'Add Application', and complete the form.

When I go to this form I am unsure what I need to put in for the Application URI field.  I have tried

https://mycompany.simpro.co/api/?format=json 
and
https://mycompany.simprocloud.com/api/format=json

and some other variations.

I have some .NET code that is attempting to Post a request, a CustomerSearch.  Whilst the code doesn't fail it doesn't bring back any Customer information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be neither.
The URI you provided is the URI that would used within your application to access the simPRO API.

The URI required here is just a page to a website that describes your integration. 
For example, Cloud Takeoff have their URI set to 'http://www.cloudtakeoff.com/' which is the main website for their product which integrates with simPRO. 
Note: This is not used in the oAuth authentication process.

To make a call to the simPRO API you can make the call using a JSON string and then POSTing this.  In the json you define two properties: 'method' and 'params'. 
Method being the procedure you want to call eg CustomerSearch. 
Params being the parameters this procedure requires: eg 'CompanyID' and 'Search'. 
Tip: you don't have to specify the name of the param as long as you have the values in the correct order.  But I would recommend you do so anyway to make the JSON easier to read and easier to troubleshoot.  Also make sure your contentType is set to application/json and encoding is UTF8.

Here is an example JSON that can be posted to the simPRO API (Bear in mind that CustomerSearch is an exact search.  You can use % as an all character wildcard if needed - so the below will find any customer that starts with 'Bob').

```
{
  "method": "CustomerSearch", 
  "params": { 
    "CompanyID": 0, 
    "Search": "Bob%" 
  } 
}
```

If you require any more help with this please feel free to email us at support@simpro.co so we can take a closer look at your current setup for you. 
If you could also provide an example of a call you are doing to CustomerSearch that would be very helpful if you are still not having any luck getting this working for you.

Hope that helps.

Daniel Sanders
Senior Software Engineer
simPRO Software

Comment: Can I integrate simPRO API in .net? is it supportable on the .net
platform?

Comment: which method we have to use for uploading invoice?